# Body tag in header AND template/footer?

Tags: wp-blog-header.php

So I'm pretty new at Wordpress development, and I'm a little confused by one thing. After going through and finishing my navigation in my header.php file, I went over to my template for the home page I'm working on. My question is: since the "body" tag is the only place you can write that actually shows up in the browser ("header" tags are for meta data etc), can I have more than one body tag? I read a little into html 5, and it seems there are more tags than just "body" now, but what's the best way to do that? I already have my menus wrapped in  and what do I do with the footer, etc? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Structure your theme so you start the `<body>` in the header and you close the `</body>` in the footer (same thing for the `<html>` tag):

header.php

```
<html>
...header content
<body>   <!--- body is started in the header, used on every page -->
```

index.php, page.php, single.php, home.php - etc

```
...content
```

footer.php

```
...footer content
</body>   <!-- body is closed in the footer, also used on every page -->
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was so confusing to me. Lol. I knew you couldn't have more than one body tag, so I just didn't get how WordPress could split it up. Makes sense though. :)

Comment: sure thing...accepting the answer would be helpful - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2913303/6887487) may help you regarding having two body tags. [is_front_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) will help you to echo body tag conditionally... either in header/footer.